# Asp.net mvc - how can I make a profile page for every user with their unique data and access it like this => domain.com/username

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Basically I want to make a profile page for every user. Like the profile pages in Twitter and Facebook.

Comment: There is no difference between user profile page or any other page.You need Model(user data) Controller(method accepting username) and View(html view to display data you got from controller).As you can notice I used words Model,View,Controller and that is what mvc stands for.You can maybe start by editing basic template when you create new app to figure out how things work.

Comment: To my understanding, the OP wants to identify the user through the route and not a normal /profile page or something. In that case, he'd have to modify the router to potentially fallback 404s to the ProfileController for example. I recommend exploring the routing documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1